# Standard normal distribution find $\mathbb{E}X(X+1)$ and $\mathbb{E}e^{3X^2/8}$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Random variable X has standard normal distribution. Find $\mathbb{E}X(X+1)$ and $\mathbb{E}e^{3X^2/8}$. My attempt is to solve:
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(x-1) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{3x^2/8} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}=2\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{8}}=2$.

Thus my question is what to do with the first example (how to calculate this integral?) and is my answer correct for the second?

Comment: I've corrected that.

Comment: Second answer is correct. For the first, note that $\mathbb{E}[X^2 +X] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] + \mathbb{E}[X] = 1 + 0$, since $X$ is the standard gaussian.

Comment: But still i do not understand how to calculate integrals $\mathbb{E}X$ and $\mathbb{E}X^2$ .

Comment: $E(e^{\frac 3 8 X^2})=(1-2\frac 3 8)^{-1/2}=2$ since $X^2\sim \chi_1^2$ and mgf of $\chi_1^2$ is $(1-2t)^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int x^2e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}=\int x\cdot xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}=-x\cdot e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}+\int e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$$
$$\int xe^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}=-e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$$
$$\therefore \int (x^2-x)e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}=-(x-1)\cdot e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}+\int e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$$

Comment: Still i do not understand because i have no idea how to deal with $\int e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}=1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2+X]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]+\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2]+\mathbb{E}[X]=\sigma^2 +0=1$$

Comment: $E[X^2]+E[X]=\sigma^2 +0$ i do not understand why we can use this

Comment: It's because the mean is zero.

Comment: I will rephrase my question. Desired integral is: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$ How do i know that that they are equal the thing you have posted.

Comment: Then see my other answer above (using partial integration).

Comment: Strictly $\mathbb{E}[X^2]+\mathbb{E}[X] = \sigma^2+\mu^2+\mu$, but as you say, this is $1$ here